# Same color is not same color on spriterenderer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, sprite

Hello i have i problem with sprtirerender colors. I have the same Color set in the inspector for both gameobjects

[image]

But when I am checking the colors in debug.log the colors are not the same anymore

[image]

I'm not changing colors in the code anywhere.

```
Color goColor = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().color;
Debug.Log(gameObject.name +" = "+ goColor);
foreach (GameObject g in go)
{
    Color color = g.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().color;
    Debug.Log(g.name + " = " + color);

    //Checkar om färgen stämmer överens med sin connection
    if (color == goColor)
    {
        objectConnection = g;
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + "Connectade till: " + g);       
    }
    else
    {
        //Debug.Log("Hittade inga matchningar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is the way how this color picker and `Color` works.

As you can see internally `Color` is actually stored using `float` components `0f` to `1f`.

If you configure the Color via the Hex value or the `0-255` option these values are converted internally and stored as `float`s.

Then further the implementation of [`Color.ToString`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/9710f1610086285933b86e42d62d2348ec51ce44/Runtime/Export/Math/Color.cs#L59) **rounds** the value for better readability to a precision of **3 decimals**.

For visualizing I made a simple

```
Debug.Log($"rounded: {color}");
Debug.Log($"actual:  {color:G9}");
Debug.Log($"hex:     {ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGBA(color)}");
```

So actually when you configure all colors via the option `RGB 0 - 1` for your printed `float` values you get

for Buttons

```
rounded: RGBA(0.271, 0.858, 0.712, 1.000)
actual:  RGBA(0.270999998, 0.85799998, 0.712000012, 1)
hex:     45DBB6FF
```

and for Blockade

```
rounded: RGBA(0.275, 0.859, 0.714, 1.000)
actual:  RGBA(0.275000006, 0.859000027, 0.713999987, 1)
hex:     46DBB6FF
```

note especially the last line: While in your screenshot the hex value would be `45DBB5`, configuring the colors via the float values actually produces `46DBB6` and `45DBB6` so there is a certain range within the float value might move around a little while the hex / bytes value stays still the same (which makes sense of course since bytes of course have way less precision than a float).

However, `Color == Color` works with an underlying conversion to `Vector4 == Vector4` and the precision for that is `0.00001` which is way more precise than makes sense on a color level.

As a solution to your case you could rather go less precise and simply configure exactly that: The hex value

```
if(ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGBA(color) == ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGBA(goColor))
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond, it made me a bit smarter at least :) That did'nt work but i went for this approuch insteed string.Format("{0:0.0}", color.r)...... for each RGBA. Beacuse I will not use so simular colors to compare and the first decimal seems to be the same allmost every time. Prob not the best solution. But can't seems to find a better way.

Comment: @skoanton you can simply use `theColor.ToString("F1")` instead ;) But basically this does the same: Use a lower precision ;)